# Migrate hibernate 3 to 5 guide needed?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, migration

I want to do an impact analysis on the migration from Hibernate 3 (3.2.6.ga) to Hibernate 5 (5.2), especially the integration with Spring. But i can't find any documentation on the subject. So any help will be grateful !

Comment: I am trying to migrate from Hibernate 4.1.0 to 5.3.1 and facing  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl error. Did you also face the same ?

Comment: can you recommend any docs.

Comment: This covers most of it: https://otter606.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/migrating-a-spring-mvc-webapp-from-hibernate-3-to-hibernate-5/

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to [hibernate's migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc) and [spring-boot 1.4 upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-13).