# cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class EntityEntry [ERROR] location: package org.hibernate.engine

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

Migrating a spring project which uses hibernate from 3 to 5, during the compilating getting the errors related to org.hibernate.engine. How to migrate this from hibernate 3 to 5?

Comment: what MySQL connector version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate hibernate 3 to 5 guide needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496327/migrate-hibernate-3-to-5-guide-needed)